# Setting Private and Public Key as a String, rather than loading from a file

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

The below code needs the path to the key file.

```
String PATHPRIVATE = "C:\\keys\\PRIVATE_KEY.pem";
String PATHPUBLIC = "C:\\keys\\PUBLIC_KEY.pem";

plugin.setSignPrivateKey(RSAEncryption.readFile(PATHPRIVATE));
plugin.setCipherPublicKeyFromFile(PATHPUBLIC);
```

Details of the plugin class.

```
 public void setSignPrivateKey(String signPrivateKey)
    {
        SignPrivateKey = signPrivateKey;
    }

 public void setCipherPublicKeyFromFile(String file)
        throws Exception
    {
        CipherPublicKey = RSAEncryption.readFile(file);
    }

public void setPublicKeyFromFile(String file)
        throws Exception
    {
        StringPublicKey = readFile(file);
    }
```

In local it works fine, but when I load it on a server as an application deployment, the need is to do away with the physical key file and rather load it as a string i.e. the contents of the key file to be loaded as a string and not from a file.

How to do something like the below.

```
plugin.setSignPrivateKey(RSAEncryption.readFile("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXQIBAAKBgQDEnL+ATwAj0hVbqoaiSaJke-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"));
    plugin.setCipherPublicKeyFromFile("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCf8X4kBjhtiK6YZ6JcW9sfGfAX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
```

Thanks.

Comment: How is anybody supposed to know what class `plugin` is an instance of? But, yes, it's possible. [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Corrections made to the question.

Comment: And what is `RSAEncryption`? Where does that come from?